# Android MaterialDatePicker UI different from Material design Documentation

Tags: android, material-components-android, android-datepicker, materialdatepicker

In my project I need to show a date picker that looks exactly like in the doc:
https://material.io/components/date-pickers#mobile-pickers

But what I see it's much different from it. I tried also the demo which I could download from the same link and it looks like mine, in fact I am attaching the Demo screen shots to compare the differences.

In particular in the demo there is a lot of margin on the sides, and also there is an horizontal line between the header and the scrolling part.

Demo:

[image]

Doc:[image]

Is there any way to obtain the same results shown in the guideline page? If not why this difference? Where is that coming from?

Comment: Doesnt that demo look that way *after* you pick the range?

Comment: It's much different no matter if before or after the selection. In the demo there is a lot of margin on the sides, and also there is an horizontal line between the header and the scrolling part.

Comment: maybe you'd need to highlight what items (like you said above) which you need to look similar so that people could get it easily.

Comment: Currently there is no way to obtain it

Comment: @GabrieleMariotti thank you, but could you tell me why it's different? Is that another version that it's planned to be released or it's just a mismatching?

Comment: @A._ I don't the reason